# Inter-process communication using pipes

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

I think maybe this is an obvious question, but I just want to be sure by asking you guys.

I'm working with parent-child process communication using the pipe system call to create a unnamed pipe.

My child process needs to gather some information and send it to its parent. My questions are:

1. Can I only send and receive strings using the write and read functions, right? I have to forget about sending structures.
2. If the answer to my previous question is "yes", the right way to transfer all the information to the parent process is to call the functions write and read several times?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to see how to do that!

Comment: I've changed "father process" to "parent process", which is not only politically correct, but also the technical term.

Answer (score 2):

You can `write()` and `read()` `struct`s just fine; use a pointer to the `struct` as the `buf` parameter.  It's when you want to do this between processes not running on the same machine that you run into problems and need to do marshaling/unmarshaling to portable representations to insure the values are understood the same way everywhere.  This includes recognizing the start and end of data "packets", since a pipe doesn't really have the concept of packets:  if all you're doing is writing a series of identical `struct`s, then you can just `write()` them and the reader can rely on `read()` returning 0 to indicate the end of the series; but if you need to send other information as well then you'll need a framing protocol to say "what follows is such-and-such `struct`", "what follows is a string", etc.

Comment: Also, `struct`s that include _pointers_ to other content are difficult to pass -- the pointers won't mean anything in the other address space.

Comment: Ok, so does not make really sense passing a linked list, right? Is it better to use any other approach?

Comment: If the only pointers are the linked list pointers, then just `write()` them in order (effectively, as an array instead of a linked list). The receiver `read()`s each element, allocates a new list entry for it, and links it into the list that it builds as it goes.

Comment: Note that even processes running on the same machine can run into trouble - for example, if one process is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit.